# golang unexpected directory layout even with right directory setup

Tags: go

I set up go package and I am getting `unexpected directory layout:` error

Full error :

```
unexpected directory layout:
        import path: _/home/ravkod/go/src/github.com/ravkod/6.824/src/mr
        root: /home/ravkod/go/src
        dir: /home/ravkod/go/src/github.com/ravkod/6.824/src/mr
        expand root: /home/ravkod/go
        expand dir: /home/ravkod/go/src/github.com/ravkod/6.824/src/mr
        separator: /
```

My GOPATH is `GOPATH="/home/ravkod/go"`

Reproduce Steps:

1. cd /home/ravkod/go/src/github.com
2. git clone git://g.csail.mit.edu/6.824-golabs-2020 6.824
3. cd /home/ravkod/go/src/github.com/ravkod/6.824/src/main
4. sh test-mr.sh

These instructions are copied from http://nil.csail.mit.edu/6.824/2020/labs/lab-mr.html

Comment: Are you using go1.13 as suggested in instructions? I think problem is using relative imports (e.g. `import "../mr"`). These really should be `import "github.com/ravkod/6.824/src/mr"`).

Comment: honestly after looking at that code, I would run. They just threw a bunch of `func main`s in the same directory, no `go.mod` anywhere, no proper Go tests, but instead some random shell script for the testing. Must better code is available than this. Do yourself a favor.

Comment: @blami i have go1.13

Answer (score 2):

The weird `GOPATH` situation should be fixed in the 2021 offering of the class: https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.824/labs/lab-mr.html (and the material/labs are not substantially changed, so you should be able to follow this version instead with no issue).

If you do want to get the old version working, you'd need to set `GOPATH` to point to the `6.824` directory, i.e. `GOPATH=/home/ravkod/go/src/github.com/ravkod/6.824` for your case. The class repo from 2020 (and earlier years) relies on this non-standard usage of `GOPATH`.

Comment: So with the 2021 version, my gopath is `GOPATH="/home/ravkod/go"` , should i clone the 2021 repo so that my directory looks like  `/home/ravkod/go/src/github.com/ravkod/6.824/src/main`

Comment: I get `../mrapps/wc.go:9:8: cannot find package "6.824/mr" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/6.824/mr (from $GOROOT)
        /home/ravkod/go/src/6.824/mr (from $GOPATH)`

Comment: @PLfan666 I haven't tested this myself, but I think the error you're getting is due to using an older version of Go. The 2021 offering of the class says to use Go 1.15; I think any version later than that should work too.