# How can this go import works?

Tags: go, development-environment, goland

I'm currently doing MIT 6.824 of distributed system lab.

I'm new to go language and using the IDE of GoLand. so I wonder why

```golang
import "6.824/mr"
```

can work properly to package mr while GoLand cannot resolve it.

[GoLand cannot resolve the import line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2jDk.png)

I think it is somehow I setting the GOPATH wrongly, I set a project GOPATH to the project root dir. So the project structure is like
"%GOPATH%/src/Dir_of_Modules_And_Go_Mod/*"

I think it is connected problem that GoLand report error of simple go.mod of

```
module 6.824

go 1.15
```

but I have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: Did you enable Go modules integration under _Preferences/Settings | Go | Go Modules_?

Comment: @colm.anseo No, the only `go.mod` in the project has been fully attached. And I actually don't think it's a problem with source files since it works well in the terminal.

Comment: @s0xzwasd that worked for import. but `go.mod` remains unresolved

Answer (score 0):

Referring to @s0xzwasd

> enable Go modules integration under *Preferences/Settings* | Go | Go Modules
> and then reboot both the remote backend and frontend dealt the import problem.

`go.mod` problem remains and refers to @colm.anseo on [golang unexpected directory layout even with right directory setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68138664/golang-unexpected-directory-layout-even-with-right-directory-setup) seems will be fixed in next version of source code by MIT. And this problem does not influence the main function of the lab, I will just ignore it.